# Slider with time interval

Tags: html, jquery, css

I found this slider in JSFiddle on https://www.cssscript.com/demo/full-width-horizontal-page-slider-with-pure-html-css/ and I have changed it little bit.

I am trying to slide the sections automatically every 5 seconds in a loop. Currently, it slides down every 5 seconds but if you just visit the page and click **Section Four** on the header in 3rd second,  after 2 seconds later it will bring you to 2nd slide but actually it should've brought you to 1st section.

I have tried to find something on thus but unfortunately, my knowledge on this very limited. Your help is much appreciated.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rubg8wyd/1/)

```
<!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>slider</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }

          .page-slider {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            background: #120103;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
          }

          header {
            background: #3e474f;
            box-shadow: 0 0.5em 1em #111;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 900;
            width: 100%;
          }

          header label {
            color: #788188;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: inline-block;
            line-height: 4.25em;
            font-size: 1em;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 0 1em;
          }

          header label:hover { background: #2e353b; }

          .slide {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 100%;
            z-index: 10;
            padding: 8em 1em 0;
            background-color: #120103;
            background-position: 50% 50%;
            background-size: cover;
            transition: left 0s 0.75s;
          }

          .slide-one { background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1800/1200?image=222); }

          .slide-two { background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1800/1200?image=333); }

          .slide-three { background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1800/1200?image=444); }

          .slide-four { background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1800/1200?image=555); }

          [id^="slide"]:checked + .slide {
            left: 0;
            z-index: 100;
            transition: left 0.65s ease-out;
          }

          .slide h1 {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translateY(100%);
            transition: transform 0.5s 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
          }

          [id^="slide"]:checked + .slide h1 {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translateY(0);
            transition: all 0.5s 0.5s;
          }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="page-slider">
          <header>
            <label class="btn slide1 active" for="slide-1-trigger">Section One</label>
            <label class="btn slide2" for="slide-2-trigger">Section Two</label>
            <label class="btn slide3" for="slide-3-trigger">Section Three</label>
            <label class="btn slide4" for="slide-4-trigger">Section Four</label>
          </header>
          <input id="slide-1-trigger" type="radio" name="slides" checked>
          <section class="slide slide-one">
            <h1>Full Width Horizontal Page Slider Demo</h1>
          </section>
          <input id="slide-2-trigger" type="radio" name="slides">
          <section class="slide slide-two">
            <h1>Section Two</h1>
          </section>
          <input id="slide-3-trigger" type="radio" name="slides">
          <section class="slide slide-three">
            <h1>Section Three</h1>
          </section>
          <input id="slide-4-trigger" type="radio" name="slides">
          <section class="slide slide-four">
            <h1>Section Four</h1>
          </section>
        </div>
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>

            $('.btn').click(function () {
                $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });



         var variableToCancelInterval = setInterval(function () {
            $(".slide2").click();
        }, 5000);

        var variableToCancelInterval = setInterval(function () {
            $(".slide3").click();
        }, 10000);
        var variableToCancelInterval = setInterval(function () {
            $(".slide4").click();
        }, 15000);
        var variableToCancelInterval = setInterval(function () {
            $(".slide1").click();
        }, 20000);
            </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: I have edited your code a bit. Try this https://jsfiddle.net/4hvs0mrb/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setInterval()` like this

```js
var i = 0;

$('.btn').click(function () {
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  i = $(this).index() + 1;
});


var Interval = setInterval(function(){
    i = (i === $('.btn').length) ? 1 : i + 1;
  $('.btn.slide'+i).click();
} , 5000);
```

```css
html, body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .page-slider {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      background: #120103;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
    }

    header {
      background: #3e474f;
      box-shadow: 0 0.5em 1em #111;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 900;
      width: 100%;
    }

    header label {
      color: #788188;
      cursor: pointer;
      display: inline-block;
      line-height: 4.25em;
      font-size: 1em;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 0 1em;
    }

    header label:hover { background: #2e353b; }

    .slide {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 100%;
      z-index: 10;
      padding: 8em 1em 0;
      background-color: #120103;
      background-position: 50% 50%;
      background-size: cover;
      transition: left 0s 0.75s;
    }

    .slide-one { background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1800/1200?image=222); }

    .slide-two { background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1800/1200?image=333); }

    .slide-three { background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1800/1200?image=444); }

    .slide-four { background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1800/1200?image=555); }

    [id^="slide"]:checked + .slide {
      left: 0;
      z-index: 100;
      transition: left 0.65s ease-out;
    }

    .slide h1 {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateY(100%);
      transition: transform 0.5s 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
    }

    [id^="slide"]:checked + .slide h1 {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateY(0);
      transition: all 0.5s 0.5s;
    }
    .btn.active{
      background : #62ce36;
      color : #fff;
      
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>slider</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="page-slider">
  <header>
    <label class="btn slide1 active" for="slide-1-trigger">Section One</label>
    <label class="btn slide2" for="slide-2-trigger">Section Two</label>
    <label class="btn slide3" for="slide-3-trigger">Section Three</label>
    <label class="btn slide4" for="slide-4-trigger">Section Four</label>
  </header>
  <input id="slide-1-trigger" type="radio" name="slides" checked>
  <section class="slide slide-one">
    <h1>Full Width Horizontal Page Slider Demo</h1>
  </section>
  <input id="slide-2-trigger" type="radio" name="slides">
  <section class="slide slide-two">
    <h1>Section Two</h1>
  </section>
  <input id="slide-3-trigger" type="radio" name="slides">
  <section class="slide slide-three">
    <h1>Section Three</h1>
  </section>
  <input id="slide-4-trigger" type="radio" name="slides">
  <section class="slide slide-four">
    <h1>Section Four</h1>
  </section>
</div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It worked very well. It also provided more usability.  Really appreciated.

Comment: Glad to hear that .. Have a nice day @t.cvmk  :-)